# Как сделать так, чтобы не задавать дату начала или дату окончания слайда

Tags: php, slider, время

Вот логика слайдера:

```
<?php
// ['name', 'ext', 'url', 'from', 'to']
$s_slides = [
    ['name1', 'png', 'https://website.com/a', '18.09.2017', '22.09.2017'],
    ['name2', 'jpg', 'https://website.com/b', '18.09.2017', '25.09.2017']
];
?>

<?php
function filterSlides($slides) {
    $filtered_slides = [];
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        if ((!isset($slide[3]) || strtotime($slide[3]) < time()) && (!isset($slide[4]) || strtotime($slide[4]) > time())) {
            $filtered_slides[] = $slide;
        }
    }
    return $filtered_slides;
}
$s_slides = filterSlides($s_slides);
?>
```

Как изменить логику отображения слайдов так, чтобы можно было не задавать дату начала, или дату окончания слайда, и чтобы в таком случае слайд отображался бессрочное время?

Comment: обращайтесь к массиву со слайдами напрямую, т.е. не подвергайте этот массив обработке функцией filterSlides().

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте второй параметр в пользовательскую функцию, и по его значению определяйте работу функции: если вызывать функцию с одним параметром, то массив со слайдами будет возвращаться этой функцией, как есть; если вызывать функцию с двумя параметрами *(вторым параметром передавать true)*, то массив будет фильтроваться по датам.

```
<?php

//  ['name', 'ext', 'url', 'from', 'to']
$s_slides = [
    ['name1', 'png', 'https://website.com/a', '18.09.2017', '22.09.2017'],
    ['name2', 'jpg', 'https://website.com/b', '18.09.2017', '25.09.2017']
];

// Массив всех слайдов
$slides_all = filterSlides($s_slides);

// Массив слайдов, отфильтрованных по дате
$slides_filter = filterSlides($s_slides, true);


function filterSlides($slides, $check = false) {
    if (!$check) return $slides;

    return array_filter($slides, function($slide) {
        return isset($slide[3], $slide[4]) && 
            strtotime($slide[3]) < time() && strtotime($slide[4]) > time();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В можете ввести простую проверку на наличие значения

```
 if (empty($slide[3]) or empty($slide[4])) {
        $filtered_slides[] = $slide;
    }
```

Весь код

```
<?php
// ['name', 'ext', 'url', 'from', 'to']
$s_slides = [
    ['name1', 'png', 'https://website.com/a', '18.09.2017', '22.09.2017'],
    ['name2', 'jpg', 'https://website.com/b', '18.09.2017', '25.09.2017'],
    ['name2', 'jpg', 'https://website.com/b'],
    ['name2', 'jpg', 'https://website.com/b', '', ''],

];
?>

<?php
function filterSlides($slides) {
    $filtered_slides = [];
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {

        if (empty($slide[3]) or empty($slide[4])) {
            $filtered_slides[] = $slide;
        }

        elseif ((!isset($slide[3]) || strtotime($slide[3]) < time()) && (!isset($slide[4]) || strtotime($slide[4]) > time())) {
            $filtered_slides[] = $slide;
        }
    }
    return $filtered_slides;
}
$s_slides = filterSlides($s_slides);

?>
```